Can I please get some testnet ETH?
I am building an app and it requires me to have a minimum of 0.2 ETH. Can you please spare some testnet ETH. My Wallet address is 0x9Aa8E7Bae673EADD8eD4c4138443532E88Cc2F56
Thanks in advance!
